# How many sequences $(a_k)_{0\le k\le 2n}$ such that $a_0=a_{2n}=1$ and every $a_k/a_{k-1}$ is $1/6$, $2/3$, $3/2$ or $6$?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many sequences $(a_k)_{0\le k\le2n}$ such that $a_0 = a_{2n}=1$ and every $a_k/a_{k-1}$ is $1/6$, $2/3$, $3/2$ or $6$, for every $k$ from $1$ to $2n$?

My try was to see that the set is $\{\frac{1}{6}, \frac{4}{6},\frac{9}{6}, \frac{36}{6}\}$ and by choosing $2n$ times from this set we will get our series but also if there are $k \  \frac{1}{6}$ for axample so there are $k $ times $\frac{36}{6}$ time we need to choose...

Comment: You are aware of the fact that $\displaystyle{a_n}+\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_n} \in \left\{\displaystyle\frac{1}{6}, \frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{2}\right\}$ is impossible for real $a_n$, aren't you?

Comment: sorry someone changed it seposed to be a_n+1 / a_n in the set

Comment: now its like i ment

Comment: Each step is $$a_{k+1}=a_k=2^{u_{k+1}}3^{v_{k+1}}$$ where $$u_{k+1}=\pm1\qquad v_{k+1}=\pm1$$ and the condition that $a_{2n}=a_0$ means that $u_k=1$ for exactly $n$ indices $k$ amongst $2n$ indices and that $v_j=1$ for exactly $n$ indices $j$ amongst $2n$ indices. Thus the desired number is $${2n\choose n}^2$$

Comment: first of all could be that $a_k\ not\ equal\ a_{k+1}$ also by your statment we need to choose $v_k = 1$ n times which is not buy must is true

Comment: i dont belive thats the answer

Comment: *typo: Replace $$a_{k+1}=a_k=2^{u_{k+1}}3^{v_{k+1}}$$ by $$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=2^{u_{k+1}}3^{v_{k+1}}$$